# Latin for 'at arm's length'

Tags: idiom

Idiomatically, the English expression 'at arm's length' means something like 'within sight, but avoiding any form of contact'. It can be used either physically or metaphorically.

I'm trying hard to find a Latin expression for it, but I can neither  trace any English translation from Latin that uses it, nor think of anything plausible that catches the idiom exactly.

Perhaps I'm just trying too hard. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm much inclined to accept _eminus_, ('not to hand' or 'at a distance'), but it's somehow not quite complete, if you see what I mean. Since asking, I have found _extra captum_ , _extra ictu_ and _ultra manu_, each of which might be useful, though I'm still uncertain. I've also thought of using _remotus_ in some way, but can't quite make it work any better than any of the alternatives.

Comment: If you're willing to forego the metaphor, the verb _arceo_ means to keep at a distance, as when Horace says "_Odi profanum vulgus et arceo_"

Comment: @Penelope Thank you. I'm trying to translate '. . we rested our glasses at arm's length upon the table' (from 'Three Men in a Boat'), and _arceo_ looks adaptable to it. I think it would also suit the metaphor. Might you now convert it into an answer?

Comment: Done!  Such a funny book, 'Three Men in a Boat'.  Good luck with the translation.

Comment: @Penelope Thank you. That's now a pretty complete survey. I'll mark it as accepted, I've actually settled for _ultra manu posuimus_ in the immediate instance; it's almost at the end of the book, and now I have to revise the whole thing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that 'at arm's length' can be construed in two slightly different ways: 'to keep at a distance' (I want nothing to do with it) or 'to have within reach' (I may have need of it at some point).  Below are suggestions for both interpretations.

The first suggestion is:

***arcere*** – to prevent from approaching; to refuse to associate with; to keep off, out

> *per ministros agere et **arcere** hostem satis habebat*
>
> he was content to act through his subordinates and to keep the enemy
>   **at distance**

Tacitus, *Annals*, 12.40

> *Odi profanum vulgus et **arceo***
>
> I despise the common crowd and **keep it at a distance**

Horace, *Odes*, 3.1.1

However, I suspect your three men may be inclined to pick up those glasses again or, at the very least, are not averse to wining and dining on another occasion, so perhaps *arcere* is too final.  My second suggestion, therefore, is:

***promptus*** – to be at hand; to have ready, at one’s disposal or command; but also to be before the eyes thereby capturing the sense of something at a short distance but still within sight.  Most often seen in the phrase ***in promptu*** (esse, habere, ponere, etc.) – within easy reach for use; or in full view; in a prominent position.

> *nam haec ipsa mihi erunt **in promptu** quae modo audivi*
>
> for I shall have the arguments I have just heard **ready to hand**

Cicero, *De Finibus*, 2.35

> *Ad salutem omnia parata sunt et **in promptu***
>
> Everything conducive to our well-being is prepared and **within our reach**

Seneca the Younger, *Epistles*, 119

> *tabernacula aperta et omnia cara **in promptu** relicta; argentum
>   quibusdam locis temere per vias velut obiectum ad praedam vidisse.*
>
> the tents were open and all kinds of valuables were left **in full sight and ready for the taking**; here and there he had seen silver carelessly flung down in the
>   lanes, as if to tempt a pillager.

Livy, *History of Rome*, 22.42 - I like how this passage captures the sense of temptation when something is at arm's length.

Another, final suggestion which could maybe keep the 'arm' of 'arm's length' imagery is:

***ad manum*** – close at hand, or as the OLD clarifies, “spatial proximity with additional idea of availability”.  However, I have to concede that this more often than not could also simply mean "to hand", as in "in one's hand".

> *ubi **ad manum** venisset hostis, tum coortos tota vi gladiis rem gerere*
>
> when the enemy had come **within reach**, then they were to assail them
>   with all their might, and settle the question with the sword

Livy, *History of Rome*, 2.30

> *haec arma habere **ad manum***
>
> these are the weapons he needs to have **within reach**

Quintilian, *The Orator’s Education*, 12.5

> *incedere inter milites, habere **ad manum** centuriones*
>
> [the women] paraded among the soldiers, they had the centurions at
>   their **beck and call**

Tacitus, *Annals*, 3.33

Answer (score 6):

The word that comes first to mind is *eminus*:

> (of fighting, striking, and sim.) At long range (and not in hand-to-hand combat). **b** (in non-military context) from a distance. [OLD]

This is, of course, the antonym of *comminus*, as in in Cicero, *De senectute* 19:

> nec enim excursione nec saltu nec **eminus** hastis aut **comminus** gladiis uteretur, sed consilio ratione sententia.
>
> For he [Scipio] would use neither sally, nor leap, nor spears **from a distance**, nor swords **in hand-to-hand combat**, but planning, reason, judgment.

Even though *eminus* would usually, I think, imply a somewhat greater distance than merely 'at arm's length,' it certainly covers the meaning 'within sight, but avoiding any form of contact.'

Comment: I'm not sure if you had this in mind when posting your answer because it's not explicitly stated but I wanted to just highlight that _eminus_ comes from _ex_ + _manus_ and so might be quite a good match for the original metaphor 'at _arm's_ length'.  I only noticed this because I was researching idioms using _manus_ myself (not with much luck though!)

Answer (score 3):

[I now see that OP already suggested *extra ictu* in a comment, but classified this as "uncertain" - However I think this example from Seneca makes a good case for it - in particular the usage out of military context. Other than that I'm not aware of all the senses of the English phrase. Clearly though, for the needed and very literal "we rested our glasses at arm's length upon the table'" the suggestion options here are not apt ]

There is a close equivalent: **teli jactu abesse** ([see L&S I.A](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DJ%3Aentry%20group%3D1%3Aentry%3Djactus2)). There are [several examples](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=teli%20iactu), or **intra jactum teli** or *extra* if someone go out of reach.

> iamque intra iactum teli progressus uterque substiterat (Virgil.) [And now in its advance each army had halted within a spear cast of the other; Loeb translation].

Not sure the phrase above was used metaphorically. But Seneca in his *Moral letters* (Letter 72) provide us with alternative that works also metaphorically for anything "'within sight, but avoiding any form of contact'" (it was nice of him to give the exact definition pretty much a perfect match to the OP's definition)

> Est adhuc genus tertium eorum qui sapientiae adludunt, quam non quidem contigerunt, in conspectu tamen    et, ut ita dicam, **sub ictu** habent.

> There is still a third class of men,—those who toy with wisdom; they have not indeed touched it, but yet are in sight of it, and have it, so to speak, **within striking distance.** (Loeb)

Let the reader be warned that [L&S (**II. Trop**)](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dictus2) presents some usages of this expression which can be quite different in meaning. But also, again, we can see there *extra* to describe opposite situation:

> Deum **extra ictum** sua divinitas posuit (SenPhil.Ben.7.7.3.9);

Also, corpus search provides yet another option which is mix of the two:

> a muro recessissent ut **extra ictum teli** essent (Livy).

[I guess one should use *ictum* instead of *jactum* when one believes the shooter is actually going to hit the target! :)]